# Any two bases of a free abelian group have the same cardinality.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am comfortable with understanding the theorem when the basis has a finite number of elements.

In the case where the basis is infinite, I find the proof very overwhelming and not so elegant.

Can someone give an accessible proof for the infinite case? Or at least a rough sketch of ideas involved in proving it?

Update: I would be comfortable if some set theoretic approach is used(in particular Cardinal Numbers).

Comment: Do you understand the proof for vector spaces?

Comment: If you are happy with a cardinality based argument, then for free abelian groups with an infinite basis, the cardinality of the basis is the same as the cardinality of the group, so the proof is easy.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is easy provided you know the following facts about infinite sets:

> - If $A$ is infinite then $|A| = |\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(A)|$, where 
>     $\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(A)$ is the set of finite subsets of $A$
> - If $f \colon A \to B$ is a map between infinite sets such that the fibers $f^{-1}(b)$ are finite for all $b \in B$ then $|A| \leq |B|$

Now suppose $B_1$ and $B_2$ are infinite bases of an abelian group $A$. Let $f \colon B_1 \to \mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(B_2)$ be the map sending an element $b \in B_1$ to the smallest subset $U \subset B_2$ such that $b$ lies in the span of $U$. By the arguments mentioned above, it follows $|B_1| \leq |\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(B_2)| = |B_2|$. Of course, by symmetry, we also have $|B_2| \leq |B_1|$.

If I am not mistaken, this proof carries over verbatim for free modules of infinite rank over arbitrary rings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nothing mysterious: The commutative free group with basis $X$ is just $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$, i.e. the (additive) group of all functions $X\to \mathbb{Z}$ with finite support (the support of $f:\,X\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $supp(f)=\{x\in X|f(x)\not=0\}$).

Now allowing denominators, if $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{(Y)}$ we have 
$$
\mathbb{Q}^{(X)}=\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\,\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}
\simeq
\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\,\mathbb{Z}^{(Y)}=\mathbb{Q}^{(Y)}
$$
we are now in the realm of vector spaces and the two bases $X,\, Y$ are in bijection.

**Remark**: In noncommutative case, you have the same property 
$$
F(X)\simeq F(Y)\Longrightarrow |X|=|Y|
$$ 
(finite or infinite case). You can (a) use cardinality argument (infinite case only) (b) abelianize and remark that $F(X)^{ab}\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ (c) use Magnus transformation which I describe now. Magnus transformation is $\mu:\,x\mapsto 1+x$ sends $X\to\mathbb{Z}\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle$ (more precisely to $1+\mathbb{Z}_+\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle$ i.e. the group of series with constant term $1$). Then you get $\mathbb{Z}.X$ by quotients (or, which amounts to the same, considering the linear part of the series obtained).

Comment: I'm just doing a second course in Algebra. Sorry to say I haven't come across any such transformations so far. Can you give some proof which involves some set theory.

Comment: I don't think your first argument makes any sense.  There's not any way to recover the set $X$ from $F_{ab}(X)$; you can only recover its cardinality.  As far as I can tell, what you are calling $\mathbb{Z}.X$ is actually the exact same thing as $F_{ab}(X)$, so you haven't actually gotten any closer to recovering $X$.

Comment: But how do you recover the cardinality of $X$ from $\mathbb{Z}.X$?  That's exactly the same as the original question...